# How to pass today date to 'new BehaviorSubject(date)' Angular 6

Tags: angular, angular2-services, angular6

I have a angular 6  use case in which, 
I need to update date in app component, which will be used by all the other components, which will be hitting mysql DB to fetch the data using select query with the above date. Which I was able to achieve, by writing a service.

Now I want the default date to be present as today or the erday, 
returned from

```
SELECT valval FROM global_configs WHERE valname = 'erday'
```

for which service was written as below

```
@Injectable()
export class ErdayService {

  public baseUrl = 'http://localhost:8080/api';
  public erday:any;  
  **private dateSource = new BehaviorSubject('Default Date');**
  currentMessage = this.dateSource.asObservable();

  constructor(private _http: Http) { }

  getErday() {

    return this._http.get(this.baseUrl + '/erday');
    }

    changeMessage(message: string) {
      console.log("getting message...",message);
      this.dateSource.next(message)
    }

    setDate(dateValue:any){
      this.dateSource.next(dateValue);  
    }
}
```

but I want to pass today's date or 'erday' received from getErday() instead of **'Default Date'** in
**private dateSource = new BehaviorSubject('Default Date');**

Can someone please help me. I'm new to Angular and services & Observables are always confusing for me.

Comment: Did my answer help?

Comment: Yes, I was able to get the today's date using your code for dateSource.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to pass today's date use javascript's [`Date`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date):

```
private dateSource = new BehaviorSubject<any>(new Date().toLocaleDateString()));
```

if you want to pass 'erday' received from `getErday()` you can use [`tap`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/utility/do.html) operator to tap into flow of `observable`

```
import {tap} from 'rxjs/operators';//
private dateSource = new BehaviorSubject<any>('Default Date');
        return this._http.get(this.baseUrl + '/erday').
        pipe(tap(result=>
        {this.setDate(result);
        return result;})
        );
```

Comment: Yes, I was able to get the today's date using your code for dateSource.
But when I pass
`getErday() {
    return this._http.get(this.baseUrl + '/erday').pipe(tap(result=> {this.setDate(result); return result;}));
    }`

It is not replacing 
'Default Date' in `private dateSource = new BehaviorSubject('Default Date');`
to `dateSource = erday` returned from `getErday()`.

Can you correct me where I'm doing wrong.

Comment: do a `console.log(result)` inside tap and share the o/p?

Comment: Was able to reach the correct result,as below
`RESULT ---------------> Response {_body: "2018-07-07", status: 200, ok: true, statusText: "OK", headers: Headers, …}`
I was calling 
`this._erdayService.currentMessage.subscribe(message =>{
    console.log("hitting....  MESSAGE",message);
      this._date = message;`
rather than 
`this._erdayService.getErday().subscribe((erday) => {
         //this._erdayService.setDate(erday.text());     
        console.log("hitting.... pie chart this._date ---->",this._date);
       this._date=  erday.text();`

Thanks VIkas, that was very helpful

Comment: Sounds great Mate and Glad I could Help!